# What is the max rtsp(over tcp) packet size?

Tags: protocols, rtsp, rtp, rfc

I didn't see about it anything in [Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326) , but when I sniffing , I saw the max rtsp packet size is 1440.

And like you can see here [RTSP - RTP over TCP](http://thompsonng.blogspot.com/2011/03/rtsp-rtp-over-tcp.html)

> RTP Data
>
> After the setup, RTP data will be sent through the TCP socket that is
> used for RTSP commands. The RTP data will be encapsulate in the
> following format
>
> | magic number | channel number | embedded data length | data |
>
> magic number - 1 byte value of hex 0x24 channel number - 1 byte value
> to denote the channel embedded data length - 2 bytes to denote the
> embedded data length data - data packet, ie RTP packet, with the total
> length of the embedded data length

I can see the 0x24 magic in each 1440 bytes.

Is that true? 1440 is the max rtsp packet size?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the MTU size/Network MTU of the network connection.
The size of the packet will be based on the MTU size only ( < less than the MTU size).

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940143/find-out-rtp-maximum-size , rtsp packet can be bigger than MTU size